# Not able to load local Image from CSS in EJS

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

Hello i am working on ejs. Inside css, I call image for background image. When page is loading image is not coming. css part is working.
if I use hosted image then it's working.

directory structure

[image]

style.css

```
.bgimg-1 {
    background: url('../img/cab.jpg');
    height: 100%;
  }
```

index.html

```
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../public/css/style.css' type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
         <span class="border"><a href="/api/login">LOGIN</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
```

Comment: change the path to   background: url('../public/img/cab.jpg'); as you are appying on class which is in index.html file.

Comment: @MohammadRaheem not working, i am already using img tag in index html.it's also not working `<img src='../public/img/cab.jpg'>`

Comment: First you will check with inspect element, image is loading or not. If loading the image just try to put .bgimg-1 {
    background: url('../img/cab.jpg');width:100%;
    height: 100px;
  }

Comment: change  background: url() to background-image: url() and everything else is ok

Answer (score 0):

Use background-image instead background

```
  .bgimg-1 {
       background-image: url('../img/cab.jpg');
        height: 100%;
      }
```